# Get metadata of @require files in tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, metadata, tampermonkey, userscripts

GM_info would only return info of the main script.

Example: GM_info.script.name wrote inside @require file "xyz" would return "abc" which is the main script's name.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

The info of the `GM_info` is prepared for the userscript. Any JavaScript from `@require` are injected as they are, and not processed.

Therefore, `GM_info` will only correspond to the userscript and not its auxiliary JavaScript.